# How to make axes fontsize in subplots similar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a group of 4 box-plots with matplotlib and I have used different ways to make axes font-size and shape similar but one of the subplots has a different shape. I do not know how to fix it. I have put my result here. I used `rcParams` also `font-size` in each sub-plot but none of them were a solution to this problem. How to make all of the axis font sizes similar in terms of shape??I know that it would be better to define a reproducible question but I was not sure in which part I made a mistake that's why I have written my code here. The code is below:
[image]

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import rcParams
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2,sharex=True,sharey=True)

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
root = r'C:\Users\Master Candidate\Desktop\New folder\Desktop\Out\NEW SCENARIO\Intersection\Beta 10\intersection'
xx=[]
percentage=[]
labels = []
gg=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in sorted(my_list) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
my_list= sorted(my_list)
percetanges = []
for directory in my_list:
    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]   
    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    CASES=sorted(CASES)    
    percentage=[]   
    for filename in CASES:        
        with open(os.path.join(root, directory,filename), "r") as file: 
            lines = file.readlines()
            x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
            y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
            g = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),100)
            h = min(y)+6
            t = max(y)-6
            xx=[]
            for i in range(1,len(x)):
                if (y[i] < h or y[i] > t):
                    xx.append(x[i])
            percent = len(xx)/len(y)
        percentage.append(percent)       
    labels.append(directory)    
    labels=sorted(labels)
    percetanges.append(percentage)
for i, x in enumerate(percetanges):
    axs[0, 0].boxplot(x,positions=[i],whis=0.001,widths = 0.6)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(labels)),labels)
plt.grid()
plt.ylim((0,1))
...
the same strategy for the rest of 3 subplots
```

At the end of the code, I finalize the procedure with saving. I mean the effort that you see above is repeated for each subplot and I do not do any thing else

Comment: We can surely help, but we need to be able to run your program. Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can work on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set the x-axis font size for multiple plots

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=14)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def example_plot(ax):
    ax.plot([1, 2])
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=14)
#     ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=16)
    
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax in axs.flat:
    example_plot(ax)

fig.suptitle('sub title', fontsize=16)
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, '$Cr$', ha='center', va='center', fontsize=16)
fig.text(0.06, 0.5, '$a$', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

[image]